# How can I pass a dynamic string as a key to a style in TS react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, parameter-passing

I want to pass the number of rows (a react native style) dynamically. I tried using 'keyof' as some here have suggested in a different issue, but it didn't work. The code itself works, I'd just like TS to stop screaming at me:

```
Type '{ backgroundColor: string; flex: number; } | { paddingTop: number | undefined; } | { marginTop: number; fontWeight: "800"; fontSize: number; textAlign: "center"; marginBottom: number; } | { ...; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.
```

Here's the component:

```
const Col: React.FC<
  PropsWithChildren<{
    numRows: number;
  }>
> = ({ children, numRows }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles[`${numRows}col` as keyof typeof styles]}>{children}</View>
  )
}
```

JSX example:

```
  <Row>
    <Col numRows={1}>
      <Text>Prompt</Text>
    </Col>
    <Col numRows={3}>
      <Text>This is the prompt</Text>
    </Col>
  </Row>
```

Here's the relevant style excerpt:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//... other styles

  "1col": {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1
  },
  "2col": {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 2
  },
  "3col": {
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 3
  },
  "4col": {
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    borderColor: "#fff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 4
  }
```

});

Comment: Did you try keyof StyleProp<ViewStyle>

Comment: No problem, usually the solution is in the error.

Comment: Casting is generally a good way to get yourself into trouble. In this case, it masks the fact that you can pass any number to the prop, but don't have a style object to match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typing is incorrect because you can't accept any number of columns; you should only allow the number of columns you actually support. For example, right now you allow passing `3.14159` to `numRows`, but don't have a style for that number.

Typescript may be smart enough to check your style names if you limit `numRows` to only what you do support:

```js
const Col: React.FC<
  PropsWithChildren<{
    numRows: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
  }>
> = ({ children, numRows }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles[`${numRows}col`]}>{children}</View>
  )
}
```

If not, you can select only the styles you have defined:

```js
const Col: React.FC<
  PropsWithChildren<{
    numRows: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
  }>
> = ({ children, numRows }) => {
  const columnStyle = (() => {
    switch (numRows) {
      case 1: return styles['1col'];
      case 2: return styles['2col'];
      // etc
    })();

  return (
    <View style={columnStyle}>{children}</View>
  )
}
```

However, you may not even need these separate styles, due to a misunderstanding of `flex`. `flex` tells the style how much space to take up relative to the other elements in its container. All you need in your case is `flex: 1`.

If you put any number of elements in your row, all with `flex: 1`, they will be weighted equally. If you put one element into a row with `flex: 4`, it will take up the whole row, because the row total is 4 and the element has 4.

You only need different numbers when you want columns of different widths, for example: 1 item with `flex: 2` and two items with `flex: 1` in a row will give the first item half the space and the other two a quarter each.